# Display Django Array without Looping

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am wondering how I can display each service array separately and not actually loop through all the django form query. This is how the loop is currently constructed. However I want to only view a few services - how can I achieve this. Here is the current loop...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="id_services_0">Services</label>
       <div id="id_services"  for="id_check_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
           {% for service in form.services.field.queryset %}
               <div style="min-height:100px;" class="col-lg-3 checkbox" id="id_check_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                   <label for="id_services_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                   <div for="id_collapse_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                      {% if service.picture %}
                         <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ service.picture.url }}" height="50" width="50" alt="">
                      {% else %}
                         <img style="display:none;" src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                      {% endif %}
                    <input class="" id="id_services_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" name="services" type="checkbox" value="{{ service.id }}" data-price="{{ service.fee }}">
                    {{ service }}<br>
                    <a class="more-details" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#id_collapse_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">More Details</a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="id_collapse_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                       <div class="well">
                       <p>
                         <small>
                            {{ service.description }}
                         </small>
                       </p>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                </label>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a few"? How do you want to restrict the ones you're looking at? First 10? Only ones with a picture? Only ones with a certain id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First 10

```
{% for service in form.services.field.queryset.all|slice:":10" %}
```

## From 2 to 4

```
{% for service in form.services.field.queryset.all|slice:"2:4" %}
```

## n-th element

Remove for-loop and

- first

  ```
  {{ form.services.field.queryset.all.0 }}
  ```
- second

  ```
  {{ form.services.field.queryset.all.1 }}
  ```

## Specific rows in services

QuerySet and Manager:

**services/query.py**

```
class ServiceQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def opened(self):
        return self.filter(status='OPEN')
```

**services/manager.py**

```
class ServiceManager(Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return ServiceQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def opened(self):
        return self.get_query_set().opened()
```

Overwrite **manager** in model:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    ....
    status = models.CharField(choices=['OPEN', 'CLOSE'], max_length=10)

    objects = ServiceManager()
```

Use in template:

```
{{ form.services.field.queryset.opened.0 }}

{% for open_service in form.services.field.queryset.opened %}
```

Comment: Thank you! And if I just wanted to target a specific one?